# How to put an event on a class that may not be in the document using jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

Here is the code I'm trying to use :

```
$(document, ".openScript").on("click", function() {
    $("#scriptWindow").modal("show");
});
```

This will call the event at any click. But because the `.openScript` isn't present at the beginning, if I do like below once, it won't be attached to the element that will be created after this code :

```
$(".openScript").on("click", function() {
    $("#scriptWindow").modal("show");
});
```

I thought it was possible to do like the first example, is there no other way than calling the second code at any time I create an element that has the `.openScript` class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Reference - .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

Following is the correct delegation syntax.

```
$(document).on("click", ".openScript", function() {
    $("#scriptWindow").modal("show");
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I love StackOverflow ! =)